# Academia -- Correct Interpretation?

Tags: word-usage

When someone says, "It's all academic" or "This one's academic", I believe that, certainly within the realm of sports context, the outcome of a game has finally been decided. The end result is a given; there is no doubt who the victor will be.
Example:

> With 20 seconds on the clock and having a 12-point lead, the Ravens will emerge triumphant. This one is academic from this point forward.

Sound logical? To have a discussion about something that is a moot point is an academic discussion:

> If I had $5 million, I'd buy two mansions and a Lamborghini.

But I don't have this kind of money, so it's all academic anyway.

Another example:

> Despite fervent begging by the shoplifter, I informed him he would be arrested for petit larceny and the police were on their way. It's now all academic.
>
> Correct to all examples given? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're mistaken in assuming *it's all academic* in the context of a sporting contest means *the outcome of a game has finally been decided*. It means the actual result is irrelevant, since *some other more significant issue no longer depends on the result* (i.e. - it's academic whether ManU win or lose the game, because they will be relegated in any case).

Comment: Same thing, really, if you think about it.

Comment: Perhaps the way *you* think about it. To me, an *academic question* in such contexts specifically means one where the answer to the question *is of no consequence*, which ***I*** think is very different to a question where the answer *has already been decided.*

Comment: What is your question? Please be specific about what you'd like us to answer.

Comment: No further questions. Ample elucidation was provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "academic" includes:

> academic — 3.irrelevant in practice: theoretical and not of any practical relevance

In the context of sports, the game being decided is *one* way for the remainder to be academic but it isn't the only way. FumbleFinger's comment provides another example:

> It's academic whether ManU win or lose the game, because they will be relegated in any case.

The key aspect of "academic" is that something is *irrelevant* and a good test is to just substitute that word:

> With 20 seconds on the clock and having a 12-point lead, the Ravens will emerge triumphant. This one is **irrelevant** from this point forward.

Which leads us to your final two examples:

> Despite fervent begging by the shoplifter, I informed him he would be arrested for petit larceny and the police were on their way. It's now all **irrelevant**.

This means that any begging is irrelevant or academic but, again, not because the *outcome* is decided. It is simply irrelevant because there is no further point to the begging.